# Issue with writing virtual layer as CSV in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis-3

I am trying to figure out why I can't write a in memory virtual layer to the file system. The folder exists

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, r'c:\temp\xyz.csv', "utf-8", None, "CSV")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>   exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   overload 1: argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
>   overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

This is the whole code

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
cFolder=os.path.dirname( unicode(iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()))
print (cFolder)
fields=[] # List of fields
Lquery=[] # List of queries to join together with Union All statement
Cquery=[] # Combined Query
for field in layer.fields():
    if field.name() not in ('Asset_ID,GID_New,GID,Depth,RL_of_Lid,US_IL,DS_IL,Install_Year,Internal_Reference_No,CWCF_hyperlink,As_con_InfoXpert_ID,As_con_2_hyperlink,As_con_3_hyperlink,Data_source,Date_Asset_added,Date_Asset_Modified,Remarks,MGM2,MGM_Survey_Required,MGM_Confidence,MGM_Comments,MGM_QA_Staff,MGM_QA_Comments,MGM_Staff3,MGM_Comment3,Phase3_MGM,Phase3_Comments,Phase3_QA,Phase3_QA_Comments,scratch'):
        fields.append(field.name())
        query = "Select '{0}' as 'Column', {0} as 'Value', count(*) as 'Unique' from {1} group by {0}".format(field.name(), layer.name())
        Lquery.append(query)
    else:
        print ('Skipped: '+field.name())
for L in Lquery:
    Cquery.append(L+' Union All ')
query=''.join(map(str, Cquery))
query=query[:-11]+' Order by Column'
print (query)
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), 'counts_'+layer.name(), "virtual" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
newfile='r\''+cFolder+'/counts_'+layer.name()+'.csv\''
print (newfile)
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer,newfile,"utf-8",vlayer.sourceCrs(),"CSV")
```

Comment: The code you give in the link refer to nothing (I didn't find anything), please copy the explicit part of the code here. Have you tried to replace the `None` with `vlayer.sourceCrs()` ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo I have added the code to this question and removed the reference. And vlayer.sourceCrs() didn't work either.

Comment: The following code works perfectly for me : `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, os.getcwd() + "/xyz.csv", "utf-8", vlayer.sourceCrs(), "CSV")`

Comment: Thanks -the problem was that it didn't need "_writer = " and should just start with "QgsVectorFileWriter..." Without this it works fine.

Comment: It works even with the `_writer` variable. The latter get (as the Documentation says) `Tuple[QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError, str]`, if all is fine, it'll contain `(0, '')`.